# ille sequatur Opis

Tags: classical-latin

In the following passage from Tibullus 1.4.68

> Ā́t quī nṓn āudī́t Mūsā́s, quī uḗndĭt ămṓrem,
> Ī́dǣǣ́ cūrrū́s ī́llĕ sĕquā́tŭr Ŏpís

From the context we know that Tibullus is outlining consequences for those who sell love and do not listen to the Muses, I just don't understand why 'following the car of Opis of Ida' is a bad consequence.
Looking at a commentary on Tibullus it says:

> Ops, Roman goddess of plenty,
> wife of Saturn, was linked with Rhea whose cult, in turn, was
> connected with the Phrygian goddess Cybele. Cybele, the Great
> Mother from Phrygian Mt. Ida, makes two famous appearances
> in Latin poetry before Tibullus, in Lucretius (2.600ff.) and
> Catullus (63 passim). The former offers a brisk description
> of her chariot and those who follow in its wake.

But that doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The priests of *Cybelē* (*Cybēbē*) the Great Mother were called *Gallī,* whose ritual of initiation consisted of self-castration in the middle of an exstatic musical performance, reenacting what Cybele's lover Atys had done to atone for his infidelity. They weren't much more conventional after that and wore women's clothes, turbans, jewelry and make-up - a Roman fresco can be seen in [this BBC article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/england/1999734.stm). Their celebrations were known for their craziness and for featuring self-flagellation. Catullus paints this graphically in his famous masterpiece, [poem 63](https://www.loebclassics.com/view/catullus-poems/1913/pb_LCL006.91.xml).

In [this part of the poem](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/660/1/3/2995-3008#3), Tibullus says that boys who have no love for poetry and the arts but are only in it to extort gifts from the lover-poet are getting no love, and might as well go and join Cybele's crazy wandering rave party for eunuchs. The poet wants to be loved for his poetic genius.

Comment: cool, i like that